# Proper way of handling error in multi await statements

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

In my code I have this statement (which works as intended):

```
async initializeConfiguration(fileName, projectPath) {
    let encryptedConfigurationFile = await this.getEncryptedConfigurationFromS3(fileName);
    let decryptedConfigurationFile =  await this.decryptConfigurationObject(encryptedConfigurationFile);

    return await this.writeConfigurationObjectToFileSystem(fileName, decryptedConfigurationFile, projectPath);
}
```

I want to properly handle any possible error that might come from any of the await operations. I thought something like this:

```
try {
    let encryptedConfigurationFile = await this.getEncryptedConfigurationFromS3(fileName);
    let decryptedConfigurationFile =  await this.decryptConfigurationObject(encryptedConfigurationFile);

    return await this.writeConfigurationObjectToFileSystem(fileName, decryptedConfigurationFile, projectPath);
} catch (error) {
    console.error(`Something bad happened: ${error}`);
}
```

But I am not sure. Is a single catch going to cover all three awaits?

Comment: FYI `return await` is always redundant, async functions will return a promise no matter what

Comment: You are correct, but it looks much better to see them explicitly returned. I don't think it hurts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it will, just like `try`/`catch` around multiple non-`await`s statements in a non-`async` function handles exceptions from all of those statements.

---

Note that your updated code as shown (if I assume it's still within `initializeConfiguration`) converts errors into resolutions with `undefined`, which makes it difficult to use `initializeConfiguration` unless nothing uses its result. If something *does* use its result, handle errors there, rather than in `initializeConfiguration` itself.